# How to login to Django Admin panel with user I created in this panel? User model was extended

Tags: django, django-users, django-auth-models

The model itself:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class UserModel(AbstractUser):
    class UserType(models.TextChoices):
        MANAGER = 'm', 'Manager'
        CUSTOMER = 'c', 'Customer'

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    type = models.CharField(choices=UserType.choices, max_length=1)
```

`USER_MODEL` is registered in settings.py.

in admin.py it's registered as:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import UserModel

admin.site.register(UserModel)
```

I can create new model in the panel with existing superuser I have. i.e. - it works.
I can add new super users with manage.py and they appear in the same place in the panel.
But later on I can't login with users I created in that panel.

saff status - checked.

The problem might be with passwords, because those created with `createsuperuser` shown hashed in the panel or I don't know even.

If I did smth completely wrong - let me know, I only need to extend users to have a couple of additional fields.

Django version 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No worries django doesn't store raw passwords it always hash the password for security reasons, imagine someone hacked into your database *people usually use the same password for all websites, not nice huh?*!

so try `python manage.py changepassword <user_name>` and write your new password

and access the shell to check is_staff attr